# Weird behaviour of LIST as parameter in recursive function

Tags: python, list, recursion

Why did below code gives this output? I was expecting different output

code is:

```
def run(n,IC):
    n+=1
    print(n,IC)
    if n==4:
        return n
    IC.append(n)
    run(n,IC)
    print("reached here",n,IC)
run(0,[])
```

it gives output:

```
1 []
2 [1]
3 [1, 2]
4 [1, 2, 3]
reached here 3 [1, 2, 3]
reached here 2 [1, 2, 3]
reached here 1 [1, 2, 3]
```

but i was expecting:

```
2 [1]
3 [1, 2]
4 [1, 2, 3]
reached here 3 [1, 2, 3]
reached here 2 [1, 2]
reached here 1 [1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is basically passed as a reference and not by value

```
def run(n,IC):
  n+=1
  print(n,IC)
  if n==4:
      return n
  IC.append(n)
  run(n,IC)
  print("reached here",n,IC)
  IC.pop()
run(0,[])
```

you need to append **IC.pop()** to reach your solution

and `1,[]` is added because you started your execution with n as 0 and IC as []

Answer (score 0):

Very first print statement, `n` is `1` but you haven't appended anything to `IC`. Therefore, `IC` is `[]`. Additionally, `IC` is a list and therefore a reference type, so the same `IC` is used across all function calls.

Answer (score 0):

First additional line in output is there because you have print before append.
Wen you give list with just variable name you actually give address to that list. 
So when you use list with same name in all functions you alway access to same list

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The lists stay the same inside and outside the functions

Once you reached this line "4 [1, 2, 3]"
your IC list is now equal to [1, 2, 3], and this will stay true for the rest of the code, so since you didnt apply any changes to the list (all you did was print the "reached..." line afterwards), its stayed the same

Idk if thats clear ^^

Comment: i got it. Thank you